# Viewport in Material Preview mode getting *rendered* [AMD ProRender]

Tags: 3d-view, radeon-prorender-render-engine

When I switch to AMD ProRender the "Material Preview" viewport mode behaves exactly like what one would expect from the "Rendered" mode: instead of showing the instant preview it starts rendering the scene. (I.e. no way one can navigate the viewport in this mode.)
When I switch to Cycles everything returns back to normal.

Have I clicked something somewhere or is this normal ProRender behavior?

Comment: I agree, there appears to be no difference between MaterialPreview and Rendered in the viewport, which is a usability/performance problem.  But it looks like one can play around with "Viewport & Preview" sampling and Quality drop-down. There appear to be some other issues, such as an abort during F12 rendering at times, or app freezeup when setting quality to Legacy, or check-box to include CPU in rendering grayed out.

Comment: It may be because how coupled eevee (the engine used in Material Preview with Cycles) and Cycles nodes are. ie Can you actually use Eevee with another render engine than Cycles ?

Comment: That could explain it. (I had no clue there is Eevee involved when using Cycles for final renders, but it makes sense.)